# JavaScript function not working for 0 value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, menu, indexing

This function is meant to find the highest variable in a list of variables, which have five id letters, and one number.  It works fine with all the other slots, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, but not 1.  I need another set of eyes here.

The getVer function takes the number from the id; so ImpHt1 with getVer would be 1, while getShtNm gets ImpHt.

```
function find_max_feat(array_input,ShtNm) {
    if (String(array_input[0]).length == 1) {
        var max = 0;
    }
    else {
        var max = getVer(array_input[0]);
    }
    var maxver = 0
    var len = array_input.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (String(array_input[i]).length > 1) {
            if (getShtNm(String(array_input[i])) == ShtNm) {
                if (getVer(String(array_input[i])) > maxver) {
                    var max = array_input[i];
                    var maxver = getVer(String(array_input[i]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

0,DmnHt1_0,AltFm1_,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

An example of the array, which is why getVer is needed.

This is for a sheet generator, to be clear, but I've been working on the entire thing for at least a few days now, maybe even a week or weeks of on and off work.

The array above is generated any time a feat is selected, and the find_max_feat array is used to find the highest version in a group; it operates off of an infinite loop since nothing else I did could get it to work the way I wanted it to.

```
function checkFeats() {
    updateFeatsel();
    t=setTimeout("checkFeats()",1000);
}

function updateFeatsel() {
    curselarray = new Array();
    var selinc = 1;
    while (selinc <= 10) {
        var selincar = selinc - 1;
        var selid = document.getElementById(String('ftlst' + selinc));
        if (getVer(selid.options[selid.selectedIndex].title)) {
                curselarray[selincar] = selid.options[selid.selectedIndex].title;
        }
        else {
            curselarray[selincar] = 0;
        }
        selinc++;
    }
    document.getElementById('debug1').innerHTML = curselarray.valueOf();
    featSelch('hlthm','ImpHt',healthom);
    featSelch('strdmgm','ImpPd',Strpdom);
    featSelch('strwhtm','ImpLi',Strwhtom);
    featSelch('strsltm','EnhIt',StrSltom);
    featSelch('endsurm','ImpEn',EndSurom);
    featSelch('endsokm','ImpDf',EndSokom);
    featSelch('intelmpm','ImpMg',Intelmom);
    featSelch('willsokm','ImpMs',Willsokom);
    featSelch('luckrllm','ImpLu',Lukrllom);
    featSelch('luckpntm','EnhLu',Lukpntom);
    featSelch('hlthbn','DmnHt',0);
    featSelch('strbn','SupSt',0);
    featSelch('luckbn','DmnLu',0);
    featSelch('endbn','Armor',0)
    document.getElementById('debug2').innerHTML = find_max_feat(curselarray,'DmnHt');
    updateAmounts();
}

function featSelch(sid,fshtnm,defval) {
    return document.getElementById(sid).innerHTML = getFeatvalue(fshtnm,defval);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are initialising `max` using `getVer(array_input[0])` instead of `array_input[0]`. If the first item is the highest and has the version number zero, the initial value is used.

Change this:

```
var max = getVer(array_input[0]);
```

into:

```
var max = array_input[0];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that actually seemed to break everything else; now the returned values are echoing in place of every field value instead of just the one that it's supposed to modify.

Comment: @Daedalus: I don't understand what you mean. What is echoed and where? Where is the modification? The code isn't modifying anything...

Comment: The function is called in another; let me get it now;

Comment: I hope that gets things in the light.  Let me know if I need to put more in.

Comment: @Daedalus: Throwing more and more code at us just complicates things. _Make a testcase_.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, alright; here's the page I've been using for de-buging and coding the script:

http://www.dimensionalwar.com/sheetgenerator/sheetformpg3.php

Comment: At the bottom of that form are two debug lines; one contains the result of the find_max_feat function, while the first contains the array generated by the selection of feats.

Comment: @Daedalus: I see where the function is called, and I tested the page, but that still doesn't tell me what you expect the result to be.

Comment: @Daedalus: In no way is that minimal. Read http://weegen.home.xs4all.nl/eelis/iso-c++/testcase.xhtml

Comment: @Guffa; if you use feat slot 1, the results don't change as expected.  If I use your code, all the figures change; DmnHt1 is only supposed to change the Health stat; not Strength or Willpower, or etc.

@Tomalak Geret'kal; I'm working on a minimal test-case now.

Comment: Well, I managed to make something close to a test case, but it's working how I wish it to..  so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @Daedalus: Ok, then you have working code and non-working code. You can compare them, and if you don't see the difference you can start re-adding code to the test case until it doesn't work any more.

Comment: I managed to fix it; I found it was a problem with an undefined variable, so I put in a check to define it:

    if (!getVer(String(array_input[0]))) {
            var max = 0;
        }
        else {
            var max = getVer(String(array_input[0]));
        }